# 'CryptQueryObject' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi, certificate, window

`#include <wincrypt.h>` has already been added, so why does the GCC-mingw32 compiler report this error?

> 'CryptQueryObject' was not declared in this scope

I'm working on Window 10.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#define ENCODING (X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING)
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    BOOL bIsSuccess;
    DWORD dwEncoding, dwContentType, dwFormatType;
    HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
    HCRYPTMSG hMsg =NULL;
    PVOID pvContext = NULL;
    string szFileName;
    szFileName ="C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\lsass.exe";
    bIsSuccess = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                               szFileName,
                               CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,
                               CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
                               0,
                               &dwEncoding,
                               &dwContentType,
                               &dwFormatType,
                               &hStore,
                               &hMsg,
                               &pvContext);
```

Comment: Try including `wincrypt.h` after `windows.h` ; switch the order of these two `#include`s.

Comment: thank you but it does'n work

Comment: Have you defined `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` (compiler command line maybe)? Besides, you shouldn't need to specify `wincrypt.h` explicitly I think.

Comment: I see  in wincrypt.h doesn'n have CryptQueryObject function in my code. But document SDK has  CryptQueryObject function in wincrypt.h.Why?

Comment: @tung that means either your Windows SDK is out-of-date and you need a new one, or you are actually using an up-to-date SDK that has removed `CryptQueryObject` since it is deprecated, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject): "***Important** This API is deprecated. New and existing software should start using Cryptography Next Generation APIs. Microsoft may remove this API in future releases.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Including `wincrypt.h` after `windows.h` otherwise it also report errors when compiling with Visual Studio.
- Link `crypt32.lib`

Compile command like this:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ test.cpp -lcrypt32
```

Edited code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#define ENCODING (X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING)
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BOOL bIsSuccess;
    DWORD dwEncoding, dwContentType, dwFormatType;
    HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
    HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL;
    PVOID pvContext = NULL;
    string szFileName;
    szFileName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\lsass.exe";
    bIsSuccess = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
        (const void*)szFileName.c_str(),
        CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,
        CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
        0,
        &dwEncoding,
        &dwContentType,
        &dwFormatType,
        &hStore,
        &hMsg,
        (const void**)&pvContext);
}
```

Comment: I did the above steps but the old error still appears. I realize that I am missing some functions in wincrypt.h like CryptQueryObject function, ... but not all of them. Does it have anything to do with the error I got?

Comment: @tung Where does your `wincrypt.h` come from? Which Windows SDK version do you use?

Comment: I use new verison Windows SDK

Comment: @tung The latest [SDK 19041](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) has defined `CryptQueryObject` function in `wincrypt.h`.